# Replacing a value with 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe where I'm trying to replace a value to 0

```
Job         Pairing
Operator    1
Operator    1
Vet         2
Doctor      3
Doctor      3
Fireman     4
Fireman     4
Police      5
Police      5
```

So I would like to change the Pairing number of 5 with 0. Anything the correlates with `Police` would get a 0

I've tried something like

```
df['Pairing'] = df({'Job' : ['Police']}).str.replace('0')
```

But seeing as they aren't strings I get a not callable error.

Any Input is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to set values:

```
In [4523]: df.loc[df.Job == 'Police', 'Pairing'] = 0

In [4524]: df
Out[4524]: 
        Job  Pairing
0  Operator        1
1  Operator        1
2       Vet        2
3    Doctor        3
4    Doctor        3
5   Fireman        4
6   Fireman        4
7    Police        0
8    Police        0
```

Comment: This worked!! I knew it was something simple I wasn't thinking of. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
dff5["Pairing"] = np.where(dff5["Job"]=="Police",0,dff5["Pairing"])
```

Easiest way. Using `where`,  will locate where `dff5["Job"]=="Police"` and then it will give it the second argument in your `np.where` which is `0`. Otherwise, it will give it the original value of `dff5["Pairing"]`.

```
    Job      Pairing
0   Operator    1
1   Operator    1
2   Vet         2
3   Doctor      3
4   Doctor      3
5   Fireman     4
6   Fireman     4
7   Police      0
8   Police      0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Job column as index you can also do:

`df.at['Police', 'Pairing'] = 0`